# How to create a simple executable application based on Python code?

Tags: python, executable

I made a Python program which takes a string as input and outputs another string after performing some functions over it. I intend to distribute it to my friends on other computers. The following is the code:

```
    s=input("Enter the tileset data : ")

    def reverse(s,i):
     if len(s)==0:
      return ""
     else:
      return s[23*(30-i):23*(31-i)]+reverse(s[:23*(30-i)],i+1)

    p=reverse(s,0)

    print ((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((p.replace('2','!')).replace('3','2')).replace('!','3')).replace('5','#')).replace('4','5')).replace('#','4')).replace('Q','$')).replace('O','Q')).replace('$','O')).replace('F','%')).replace('G','F')).replace('%','G')).replace('I','&')).replace('H','I')).replace('&','H')).replace('J','^')).replace('K','J')).replace('^','K')).replace('M','}')).replace('L','M')).replace('}','L')).replace('>','*')).replace('?','>')).replace('*','?')).replace('A','(')).replace('@','A')).replace('(','@')).replace('B',')')).replace('C','B')).replace(')','C')).replace('E','_')).replace('D','E')).replace('_','D')).replace('6','{')).replace('7','6')).replace('{','7')).replace('8','+')).replace('9','8')).replace('+','9')).replace('<','[')).replace('=','<')).replace('[','=')).replace(':',']')).replace(';',':')).replace(']',';')
```

I want to make a simple executable application using this python code, so that anyone who doesn't have Python installed on their computers may run it.

I don't know anything related to .exe programming. It would be great if someone could create the application for me.

Comment: You know that you don't have to wrap your `replace()`s in parentheses, right? You can simply chain them like this: `string.replace(args).replace(args).replace(args)...`

Comment: Better yet, you can use `string.translate` or even `re.sub`

Answer (score 1):

For Windows there is [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)

But I never used it. So I can not say anything about it.

Comment: I used it. But I don't know the code to take input from user. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use cx_Freeze. It's great. And it works, unlike py2exe and pyinstall.

You can run it as an stand-alone script or import in your setup.py

Example :

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

copyDependentFiles=True

includes = ["lxml", "lxml._elementpath", "lxml.etree", "gzip",    
"encodings.cp949",    "encodings.utf_8", "encodings.ascii"]

setup(name='gearfacts',
      version = "1.1",
      options = {
          "build_exe" : {
               "includes": includes,
           },
      },
      executables=[Executable('app.py')],
)
```